# PAY PAL IPN stop working

Tags: paypal-ipn

My code stop working, I have made some changes like `$res=trim($res);` as I saw in another question but still not working.
The code was perfectly working including automatic post in Facebook and Tweeter.

Please, could someone check my code and help me to fix it?

```
<?php

// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////Begin Script below./////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";


// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['fir st_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email =  "xxxxxx@gmail.com";         //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "xxxxx"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "xxxxx"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "xxxxx"; //your MySQL Database Name

if (!$fp) 
 {
   // HTTP ERROR
 } 
else 
 {
   fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
   while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
      $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
      $res=trim($res);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
        //if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED\r\n") == 0) 
        {
           //create MySQL connection
           $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
           or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
           //select database
          $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
           or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
           $fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
           $fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");
           //check if transaction ID has been processed before
           $checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".$txn_id."'";
           $sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
           $nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);

            if ($nm == 0)
              {
               //execute query     
               $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,receiver_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$receiver_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
               $result = mysql_query("insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,receiver_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$receiver_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')")
               or die("Default - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
             {
                   $consumerKey    = 'ccYgLrtBUrgIPJDQ';
                   $consumerSecret = '4qXLLXdQPcKqAqKscYQH9p9m3cznyVWYc4v8';
                   $oAuthToken     = 'uVgkQTC0BLNT9V9vTpc25poxDgIomCgMbw';
                   $oAuthSecret    = 'L8rfc6A1Ii5cMeuYEhf6hwkc3aATyo';
                   require_once('twitteroauth.php');
                   $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);
                   $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Last donation  US$ '.$mc_gross.' to '.$item_name.' '));
                 } 
                mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");

               $sql = mysql_query(" UPDATE cadastros SET amount='$mc_gross'-'$mc_fee'+amount, mc_gross = '$mc_gross' , mc_fee ='$mc_fee', payment_date = '$payment_date',pay_date = now() WHERE receiver_email='$receiver_email'");                                                                            
               $result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );                                                                       
              }  
         else
          {
           // send an email
             mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
          }

         // if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
     }

          else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
            {
             // log for manual investigation
                 mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
            }
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, someone has a code that is working to send me?

Answer (score 0):

The HOST tag in the header has to match the URL you are using with fsockopen.

Try this:

```
$sandbox = 1;
$paypalURL = $sandbox ? 'www.sandbox.paypal.com' : 'www.paypal.com';

// Create http header
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Host: $paypalURL\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"; 
// Post back to PayPal system to verify
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$paypalURL, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```